# Static methods in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, static-methods

using asp.net mvc 4,

I created a class with a static method like this

```
public  class StaticClass
{
    public static int val { get; set; }

    public static string ReturnValueBasedOnInput(int n)
    {
        string res;
        switch (n)
        {
            case 101:
                Thread.Sleep(30000);
                res = "Long lasting response: 101" + val;
                break;
            default:
                res = n.ToString() + " was provided..." + val;
                break;               
        }

        return res;
    }        
}
```

it is called from my controller :

```
    public ActionResult Index(int id = 1)
    {            
        ViewBag.returnValue = StaticClass.ReturnValueBasedOnInput(id);
        return View(id);
    }
```

I expected that when i call the method with a parameter value of 101 the application should be blocked for 30 secs, but it remains responsive. I thought since this is a static method it should be blocked for 30 second for all incoming method calls. can someone explain what happens here?

Comment: Are you getting the expected return value `Long lasting response: 101`?

Comment: Yes, I created a test case and everything is working like this is not a static method, eg. when I call with 101 and start to provide different numbers in a new session those numbers are shown until 30 secs is finished, then 101 is shown with the next number provided

Comment: How are you calling Index?  Is it an AJAX call or a page call?

Comment: Are you saying it isn't blocking at all or is only blocking for the request that passed 101? Just because the class and method is static, it doesn't mean only 1 thread can access at a time. It means all threads will share the memory and contents of the object. Only the thread that called the method with '101' should block while the others traverse happily. If you want 1 thread to access, you need to use locking.

Comment: It is working just as you said, so can you please answer my question in the comments of answer 1?

Answer (score 1):

The thread handling the request to the `Index` action with `id=101` of your controller should be blocked. Threads handling other requests of other sessions will not be blocked. Even other requests for the same session may not be blocked depending on `ReadOnly` session attribute of corresponding controllers `[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]`.

Comment: so is it a good idea to use a static method for retrieving data from database in the service layer, for reporting for example?

Comment: It is a normal idea, you have to remember that several threads may execute this method at the same time, therefore you should not be modifying any of the static class fields (such as `val` in your example), or do it using locking.

Comment: Thank you very much Igor, I got my answer, since I read everywhere that generally it is not a good idea to use static methods in threaded applications